# Create dwl library for common dwl mapping in mule 4

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mulesoft, mule4, mule-esb

My requirement is to do externalized dwl mapping files outside of the project and not include in src/main/resources folder.

To fulfil the requirement I need suggestion how I can proceed. Please check the below point provide any article or the way how I can implement-

1. Can I keep dwl folder outside of the project?
   I tried to provide the file path in transform message like this #[MULE::${dwl.location}]/common/set-client-secret.dwl but this is not working.
2. Is it possible to create dwl library for all dwl mappings files and can we import in transform message?

example: Below we have dwl mapping file that should be inside common library and in mule flow how can import just defining something like import::bad_request.dwl

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{
  message: "Bad request",
  error: error.description default ""
}
```

Comment: Questions in Stackoverflow should focus in only one topic. I recommend to create a separate question for 2) and include more context. Questions that lack focus could be closed as "Needs more focus" https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to reference DataWeave files directly from outside the project directory using standard methods. What is possible is to [create DataWeave libraries](https://developer.mulesoft.com/tutorials-and-howtos/dataweave/dataweave-extension-vscode-getting-started/) and [publish them to Anypoint Exchange](https://developer.mulesoft.com/tutorials-and-howtos/dataweave/dataweave-libraries-in-exchange-getting-started/) for reuse in applications. If you don't want to use Exchange is probably possible to use the libraries as any other jar file, deploying to a Maven repositories and referencing it as a dependency in your project pom.